# Cannot apply stroke to clipped masked objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have one layer of clipped masked objects and when i try make a stroke to them applyes on the entire object loosing the clipped appearance. How do i do to make only the stroke?
Is in Ilustrator CC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double click the item to edit in isolation mode. That is when you should apply the stroke.